# Given a Spring Data Rest URI, How Do you find the associated target repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm building an application using Spring Data REST and implementing an interceptor pattern using a `MappedInterceptor` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959143/1474069). The interceptor works as expected and it intercepts `@RestControllers`.

Now, using the parameters available in the `preHandle(…)` method signature (these include: `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler => can be casted to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod`), how can I access the RestRepository class or repository Method being invoked (the `getMethod()`, from the HandlerMethod class, works great with Concrete classes, but it does not work with Repository interfaces, it ends returning a RestAbstractController class that invokes the target repository through reflection)???

Why I need this?

Because, I´m doing a cross-cutting logic that needs to access the Repository interface to find a specific business annotation, if the annotation is present, some logic is done (like setting `MDC` special values, for example)...

Thanks...

Comment: Can you provide code samples of what you have tried and isn't working?

Comment: I believe that the code won´t help here ... As I said, using the `getMethod()` from `org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod` I can get a reference to a concrete class and from there I can lookup my annotation through reflection ... This approach only works with concrete classes implemented by myself ... However, Spring JPA Rest Repositories are invoked by a concrete class provided by Spring, so the target repositories are being wrapped by such class and I don't know how to access them ...

Answer (score 4):

The most flexible way to generically lookup and use Spring Data repositories is through the `Repositories` and `RepositoryInvoker` abstractions.
The former provides by-type lookup abilities of metadata about the repositories and the repositories themselves. The latter allows generic invocation of CRUD and query methods on those repositories. This additional abstraction is necessary as Spring Data repositories don't have to implement a special interface as long as they expose methods that are syntactically equivalent to the ones provided in Spring Data's `CrudRepository`.

### The general way

If you know about the actual domain class you're trying to access the repository for you can get an instance of `Repositories` injected into your class. That one in turn allows you to lookup entity and repository information as well as the repository itself.

As the latter doesn't have to implement a dedicated interface mandatorily, `Repositories.getRepositoryFor(…)` only returns `Optional<Object>` which isn't too helpful if you want to actually do stuff on the repository. `RepositoryInvokerFactory` allows you to create `RepositoryInvoker` instances that allow you to invoke certain methods on a repository explicitly independent of way they're actually declared.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SomeComponent {

  private final Repositories repositories;

  public <T> void someMethod(Class<T> type) {

    … = repositories.getEntityInformation(type);

    RepositoryInvokerFactory factory = new DefaultRepositoryInvokerFactory(repositories);
    RepositoryInvoker invoker = factory.getInvokerFor(type);
    Optional<T> entity = invoker.invokeFindById(4711);
  }
}
```

Note, that a `Repositories` instance is available as Spring Bean if you use Spring Data REST. If you don't simply declare a bean for it. All it needs is a `ListableBeanFactory`.

### Spring Data REST

With Spring Data REST in the picture on might get into the need to lookup the repository that's backing a particular path segment of the URI. That additional knowledge is encoded in `RepositoryResourceMappings` which can be used to find out about the domain type that's accessed:

```
RepositoryResourceMappings mappings = … // get injected

Optional<Class<?>> domainType = mappings.stream()
  .filter(metadata -> metadata.getPath().matches(pathSegment))
  .findFirst()
  .map(ResourceMetadata::getDomainType);
```

The discovered type can now be used to obtain the repository instance from `Repositories`. Spring Data REST also provides a preconfigured instance of `RepositoryInvokerFactory` that applies potentially registered custom `EntityLookup` instances. I.e. using that is preferred to creating an own one like shown above.

Comment: What about if I don't have information about the actual domain class?? I only have is the URL REST endpoint through `HttpServletRequest`??

Comment: Then you have to find out how to map the URI back to your domain type? Nobody except you knows, which URIs handle which entities.

Comment: Not really, what I want is this: Given an URI, ask to spring which will be the repositoriy (interface)  that it is gonna to be called (Spring knows such mapping somehow, because It calls the right repository given an URI) ... then analyze such interface to lookup my custom annotation ...

Comment: It would've been helpful if you explicitly had mentioned that you seem to be using Spring Data REST. It's in one of the tags used but the problem description doesn't reveal that. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I would like to extend it by adding that you can also obtain the Interface that defined the Data repository by using the repositories instance and asking for the one defined for that Domain class: repositories.getRepositoryInformationFor(type).getRepositoryInterface()

Comment: @guilleHeuer – I thought I mentioned that by "The former provides by-type lookup abilities of metadata about the repositories…".